# Decimal button in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just managed to do a decimal migration.
But all of the sudden a weird button appeared next to the field.
Any idea how i can remove it or maybe the name of that weird thing?
Its on the right side of the field. And it has arrow up and down.
(I´m very new to coding)

This is the code

```
<%= f.input :phone, as: :decimal, placeholder: "Phone Nr.", label: "Contact", input_html: { rows: "1"} %>
```

Sorry, not allowed to post images yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a numeric input from HTML5, you may see [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-handling-numeric-inputs-using-the-number-and-range-input-types.html#fbid=_kaOfTvvp8y) for description.

You may control input type by setting `as` parameter, [possible values](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/README.textile#the-available-inputs).

For most fields you may omit it,  formtastic will guess correct input type by attribute type or name.

I think it would expect the phone attribute to be of a string type. If you need some why to keep it numeric but normal phone input is required, force it with `as: :phone`. But then you should have some preprocessing for this value before writing it to attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The weird button is a part of number input. [Read here about most common input types available in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp). It's purpose is to enter a decimal number. HTML5 introduced new input semantics so instead of boring box your browser will render additional controllers on top of the input depending on it's type.

What you probably want is a `tel` input. Rails provide `<%= telephone_field() %>`. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) is the list of all form helpers available in Rails.

Also consider using `string` for your phone number and validate it on model instead